python workers get stuck randomly
I'm encountering an issue with a multiprocessing script in Python. The script processes flights using a function process_one_flight . Individually, each step of the function works as expected, but when executed via multiprocessing workers, the script occasionally gets stuck at random steps of the process_one_flight function.. I have been unable to reproduce the bug in a consistent manner, which complicates troubleshooting.
Here's a simplified version of the script:
def _worker(q: Queue, unprocessed: list):
    while not q.empty():
        flight = q.get()
        try:
            process_one_flight(flight, pair=pair, baseline=baseline, force=force)
        except Exception as e:
            unprocessed.append(flight)
            print(f"Error processing {flight}: {e}")

manager = Manager()
q = manager.Queue()
unprocessed = manager.list()

for world in db_path.iterdir():
    if "flight" not in world.name or world_name not in world.name:
        continue
    for split in world.iterdir():
        flight_list = list(split.iterdir())
        flight_idx = [int(flight.name) for flight in flight_list]
        sorted_idx = np.argsort(flight_idx)
        sorted_flights = [flight_list[i] for i in sorted_idx]
        for flight in sorted_flights:
            print(flight)
            flight = Flight_lw(world=world.name, split=split.name, flight_name=flight.name)
            flight.add_db_path(db_path)
            flight.build_folders()
            q.put(flight)

if num_workers > 1:
    workers = [Process(target=_worker, args=(q, unprocessed)) for _ in range(num_workers)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
else:
    _worker(q, unprocessed)

Any idea what's happening or how to reproduce the bug ?

If two processes simultaneously determine that q is not empty while there is only one element remaining, one of the processes will stack at q.get(). Also, Queue.empty is not reliable.

Queue.empty is not reliable for multiprocessing.Queue instance but this is a managed queue that is backed by a queue.Queueinstance. It is reliable but slow. Also better would be to use a while True loop and inside use a non-blocking q.get(block=False) and catch the potential queue.Empty exception. Thus no testing of whether the queue is empty or not is required and no time is wasted with a 1 second timeout that LogicDaemon's solution has incorporated.

the race condition is here
    while not q.empty():
        flight = q.get()

if another thread manages to q.get() the last item of the queue after the current thread checked that not q.empty(), the q.get() of the concurrent thread will get blocked:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue

If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

You'll need to re-think how you read the queue to avoid the race conditions, I'd say, do something like:
while True:
    try:
        flight = q.get(block=true, timeout=1)
    except Queue.Empty:
        break

    try:    
        process_one_flight(flight, pair=pair, baseline=baseline, force=force)
   ...

or instead of catching Queue.Empty and breaking you might elect for just
while True:
    flight = q.get(block=true, timeout=1)

    try:    
        process_one_flight(flight, pair=pair, baseline=baseline, force=force)
   ...

which will effectively stop the worker, albeit with an exception logged depending on your logging configuration.
P.S. Oh an by the way, check the example at the bottom of the doc page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html
It might be reasonable to use .get() and keep the workers intact instead of letting them destroy themselves when the queue is empty. Just create them with Process(..., daemon=True).

LogicDaemon has noted correctly that you have a race condition, but a far simpler solution that is more efficient is to not use the high-overhead managed queue and list instances that you have and to use a multiprocessing pool.
Now the worker function, _worker, just processes a single flight and returns None if there was no exception, otherwise the flight whose processing resulted in the exception. Since you have not posted a a complete, working program (you are missing import statements, function declarations), the code below is a complete, albeit simplified example of what I suggest you do:
USE_MULTIPROCESSING = True

def process_one_flight(flight):
    if flight in ('bbb', 'ddddd'):
        raise RuntimeError('oops!')
    return len(flight)

def _worker(flight):
    try:
        process_one_flight(flight)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {flight}: {e}", flush=True)
        return flight  # return problematic flight
    else:
        print('Successfully processed flight', flight, flush=True)
        return None  # No error

def main():
    flights = ['aa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'ddddd', 'eeeee']

    if USE_MULTIPROCESSING:
        from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

        pool_size = min(len(flights), cpu_count())
        with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
            unfiltered_unprocessed = pool.map(_worker, flights)
    else:
        unfiltered_unprocessed = (_worker(flight) for flight in flights)

    unprocessed = list(filter(lambda result: result is not None, unfiltered_unprocessed))
    print('unprocessed =', unprocessed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
Successfully processed flight aa
Error processing bbb: oops!
Successfully processed flight cccc
Error processing ddddd: oops!
Successfully processed flight eeeee
unprocessed = ['bbb', 'ddddd']

